# Remove characters from image url retrieved as string?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do I remove the image resolution from the string below in Node.js?

> http://asset.beyonce.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/XIII6614-800x800.jpg

I'd like it to be just

> http://asset.beyonce.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/XIII6614.jpg
>   without the -800x800!

```
var image = 'http://asset.beyonce.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/XIII6614-800x800.jpg';

image = image.replace(new RegExp("^(.*?)-\d+x\d+\.([^/]+)$", "g"), "")
    console.log(image);
```

The above code isn't working for some reason?

Comment: `/\-\d+x\d+/` would work, maybe a bit broad though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var image = 'http://asset.beyonce.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/XIII6614-800x800.jpg';

image = image.replace(/^(.*?)(-\d+x\d+)(\.[^/]+)$/, "$1$3");
console.log(image);
```

You can use this regex, refering to matched groups when replacing.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is matching the url up-to the dash and `.jpg`. And the replace will remove everything except `-800x800`.

Please have a look [here](https://regex101.com/r/jA4fS8/1) for the result of the regex.

You could use `regex.match` and join the result. Or use a regex replace like this:

```
image = image.replace(new RegExp("-\d+x\d+", "g"), "")
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the regex isn't fulfilling what you want it to do.

Also note that `new RegExp` is a bit overkill as you can just define it right away within forward slashes.
Below code should help.

```
var image = 'http://asset.beyonce.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/XIII6614-800x800.jpg';

image = image.replace(/-\d+x\d+\./g, "")
console.log(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your regexp match the whole string, so you should get an empty result.

Then you don't need the "g" as it matches multiple times, and you just need to remove the part at the end of the URL.

And last, you have to put in the substitution string the saved file extension.

Use regexp literal:

```
image = image.replace(/-\d+x\d+\.([^/]+)$/, ".$1");
```

Don't forget the **$** char at the end of the regexp.